# Laravel8.x - Getting exception while accessing belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel

I have a model class created in  my laravel 8.x application with the code as given below

```
class City extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'portal_cities';
    
     public function belongsTo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class); // also tried giving 'state_id' as second parameter
    }
}
```

I have the portal_cities table as below
[image]

When i am trying to access the following code

```
 $eventobj = App\Models\Event::find(1);
    echo $eventobj->location->city->name;
```

It is giving the following error

```
Declaration of App\Models\City::belongsTo() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = NULL, $ownerKey = NULL, $relation = NULL)
```

Can you please tell me what is causing the error and what can be done to rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change relation method name
for example:

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class); // also tried giving 'state_id' as second parameter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't create `belongsTo()` function as it is core function in model

so you need to change this

```php
class City extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'portal_cities';
    
     public function state() // change this name
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class); 
    }
}
```

you can check core function here
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L193